# How to access the variables created within a `with` statement

Tags: python, introspection

I have defined a python context class and a `Test` class in a file:

```
class Test(object):
  pass

class MyContext(object):
  def __init(self):
     self._vars = []
  def __enter__(self):
    pass
  def __exit(self, ....):
    pass
```

In another file using that context:

```
from somewhere import Test, MyContext
with MyContext() as ctx:
  mytest = Test()
```

So what I want to achieve is that when I exit the context, I want to be aware of the `mytest` instance created and add it in the `ctx._vars = [<instance of Test >]`.

I don't want to have a `ctx.add_var(mytest)` method, I want those `Test` instances to be added automatically to the `ctx` instance.

Comment: Using the context doesn't mean that `ctx` is aware of the code inside your `with` statement.

Comment: correct. an internediate solution would be to pass the locals() to ctx with a final line like. `ctx.get_nodes_from_locals(locals())` but i have to filter whats just inside the ctx and get rid of the outside that could exists. not bulletproof at the moment.

Comment: The closure is evaluated when you enter context.  Changing that context from within suggests that you're using the wrong design tools for whatever you're designing.

Comment: (I removed the "python-contextvars" tag as those are something not related with the "context" managed by a with-block

Answer (score 1):

That is possible of being done, using Python's introspection capabilities, but you have to be aware this is not what the `with` context block was created for.

I agree it is a useful syntax construction that can be "deviated" to do things like what you want: annotate the objects created inside a code block in a "registry".

Before showing how to do that with a context manager consider if a class body would not suffice you. Using a class body this way also deviates from its primary purpose, but you have your "registry" for free:

```py
from somewhere import Test, MyContext
class ctx:
  mytest = Test()

vars = ctx.__dict__.values()
```

In order to do that with a context manager, you have to inspect the local variables at the start and at the end of the `with` block. While that is not hard to do, it wuld not cover all instances of `Test` created - because if the code is like this:

```py
mytests = []
with Mycontext as ctx:
    mytests.append(Test())
```

No new variable is created - so code tracking the local variables would not find anything. Code could be written to look recursively into variables with containers, such as dictionaries and lists - but then `mytest()` instances could be added to a container referenced as a global variable, or a variable in other module.

It turns out that a reliable way to track `Test` instances would be to instrument the `Test` class itself to annotate new instances ina  registry.  That is far easier and less depentend on "local variable introspection" tricks.

The code for that is somewhat like:

```py
class Test(object):
  pass

class MyContext(object):
    def __init(self, *args):
        self.vars = []
        self.track = args
        self.original_new = {}

    def patch(self, cls_to_patch):
        cls_new = getattr(cls_to_patch, "__new__")
        if "__new__" in cls.__dict__:
            self.original_new[cls_to_patch] = cls_new

        def patched_new(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = cls_new(*args, **kwags)
            self.vars.append(instance)
            return instance

        cls_to_patch.__new__ = patched_new        

    def restore(self, cls):
        if cls in self.original_new:
            # class had a very own __new_ prior to patching
            cls.__new__ = self.original_new[cls]
        else:
            # just remove the wrapped new method, restores access to superclass `__new__`
            del cls.__new__

    def __enter__(self):
        for cls in self.track:
            self.patch(cls)
        return self

    def __exit(self, ....):
        for cls in self.track:
            self.restore(cls)
        ...


from somewhere import Test, MyContext
with MyContext(Test) as ctx:
  mytest = Test()
```

Comment: Very interesting approach. Thx

Comment: The only problem above is you re just tracking the class passed as args to the context, but not the actual instances created inside the context.